# What is the connection between Jet and James?

Tags: comics, rachel-rising, terry-moore

Jet is Rachel's best friend, and her loyal ally in later issues.

When

> Jet is poisoned

Rachel whispers her old name to her, "Bryn Erin", but addresses not Jet but James. After that, James, Rachel's friend who apparently died in 17th century, "awakens" in Jet's body.

James supposedly swallowed a part of the Tree (from the Garden of Eden) that made him immortal; problem is, he was already dying. If he became immortal, he shouldn't have died, and should've kept his own body. If he died, how did he come back?

Am I supposed to assume he *reincarnated* in Jet, after 4 centuries? If so, why in Jet, and why only now? And where did he go after Jet came back?